# Load UIViewController that has no Xib

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a class that is a subclass if `UIViewController` with no xib connect to it ,,,

The class contains a method that will `presentViewController` an instance of `TWTweetComposeViewController` (to make a tweet) .

So when I need to call that method I need the view to be presented using `presentViewController`, but its not working ,,, here is what I am doing:

// Here is the method in Class B (subclass of UIViewController)

```
@implementation TwitterManager
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(postTweetImage:) name:Twitter_UploadImage object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

+(TwitterManager*)sharedInstance
{
    if(object == nil)
        object = [[TwitterManager alloc] init];

    return object;
}
-(void)postTweet
{
    if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        NSLog(@"can send tweet postTweet");
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        // Set the initial tweet text. See the framework for additional properties that can be set.
        [tweetViewController setInitialText:@"Hello. This is a tweet."];

        // Create the completion handler block.
        [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            NSString *output;

            switch (result) {
                case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    // The cancel button was tapped.
                    output = @"Tweet cancelled.";
                    break;
                case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    // The tweet was sent.
                    output = @"Tweet done.";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];

            // Dismiss the tweet composition view controller.
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];

        // Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
        [self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"can not sen a tweet");
    }
}
@end
```

// In class A I am trying to call it like this

```
TwitterManager twitterObject = [TwitterManager sharedInstance];
    [twitterObject postTweet];
```

So what is the way to create the view that will be responsible for loading the Twitter object `presentViewController`

Comment: First, you should tell us more about the problem than just "it's not working". Second, you should be calling UIViewController's designated initializer: `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: Oh sorry for that ,, the problem is when I try to tweet by calling 'postTweet' the tweet dialog doesn't appear

Comment: I don't want to use nib(Xib) ,,, and I guess `-initWithNibName:bundle:` method will not work

Comment: what is `TwitterManager` ? is it a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: yes ,,, `TwitterManager` is subclass of `UIViewController`

Comment: @MohamMadSalah You still need to call the designated initializer, which for UIViewController is `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. If you don't want to load your view from a nib, that's fine -- just override `-loadView` to create the view instead of loading it from the nib file.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourTweetViewController * tweetViewController = [[YourTweetViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It doesn't work I got this error ,,, `loaded the "TwitterManager" nib but the view outlet was not set` ,,, can you provide me with a setup for `-(id)init` to load the view of TwitterManager